# Little ecommerce: 1+ seller, payment via Paypal based on seller configuration

Tags: 7, commerce, payment-gateways

I need to create a little e-commerce site where I can have more than one seller, but the payments are made via Paypal, with seller's data.

I cannot have different products from different sellers in my cart (and this is OK).

Is there a little e-commerce module for this? I don't want use Drupal Commerce or Ubercart, if possible.

Which module could I use for payments?

Comment: _"I don't want use commerce or ubercart"_...might be good to explain _why_ you don't want to use the two most popular e-commerce solutions for Drupal?

Comment: I guess this is similar to the "I don't want to use the Views module, if possible" case. It could be the Views module is excessive for doing a single, simple thing. Still, knowing why you don't want to use Drupal Commerce or Ubercart could help getting better answers. It could be you have a misconception about those modules, and you could really use them.

Comment: @Clive: I don't want to use commerce because is big and I need to give to the seller user the possibility to insert the product, and with "commmerce" I need, for first, create the product (sku and other data) and after create the display. But for N different seller users this is a nightmare, so: how can I (and seller user) insert product and display in 1 form only ? And, again, commerce can not permit to use different paypal settings for different buyer. If this is possible, how ? Via rules I can block to insert different seller's product in a sigle buyer cart, but for the payment ?

Comment: Commerce really isn't that big at all, it's beautifully modular so you only need enable the modules you're actually going to use. The whole separation of product/display was solved a while back, you can do it all on a single page now easily (install Commerce Kickstart for an example). As for payment, you're probably going to have to write a custom module for that; I looked into exactly the same thing recently (multiple sellers with a PayPal account each) and didn't find anything for Drupal at all

Comment: @Clive: thanks for the reply. I can not install commerce kickstart because I need to install commerce in a D7 site in construction, so: which modules I need to install to have "1 page entry" ? . For paypal: if you have resolved your (and possibly my) problem: how ? is it possible to see your module ? Or can you give me more info ? Thanks for all.

Comment: Sorry I'm not really sure about the one page entry and the project to write that module won't start for another couple of months. It sounds like you might need to hire a Drupal developer to help you out with this

Comment: @Clive: thanks however. I'm a drupal developer since version 5.x

Comment: Didn't mean any offence :)

Comment: @CLive: It was only to respond to your statement "you might need to hire a Drupal developer". I learn every day new things. In this site too. And thanks again four your replies to my problem.